# This code changes the textbox instantly to red. I want it like, click button then red, again then green

Tags: c#, button, if-statement

This code changes the textbox instantly to red. I want it like, click button then red, again then green.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

    if (textBox1.BackColor.Equals(System.Drawing.Color.Black)) 
    {
        textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }



    if (textBox1.BackColor.Equals(System.Drawing.Color.Red))
    {
        textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }



    if (textBox1.BackColor.Equals(System.Drawing.Color.Green))
    {
        textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    }



    if (textBox1.BackColor.Equals(System.Drawing.Color.Blue))
    {
        textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only on Stack Overflow can you get six different ways to change the color of a textbox.  The only thing missing here is the Linq version.

Comment: @RobertHarvey and, except for Erby's answer, they all show poor practice/miss the point.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Added LINQ version.  Not the best but it is tested and it works.  Just to be facetious...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use an `else if`:

```
if (textBox1.BackColor.Equals(System.Drawing.Color.Black)) 
{
    textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
} 
else if (textBox1.BackColor.Equals(System.Drawing.Color.Red))
{
    textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
} 
else if (textBox1.BackColor.Equals(System.Drawing.Color.Green))
{
    textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
} 
else if (textBox1.BackColor.Equals(System.Drawing.Color.Blue))
{
    textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

What you were doing is changing it to `red`, then checking if it is `red` and changing it to `green`. By using `else if` you won't execute the `if red` if it is `black`.

Also, as Tim points out in the comments, you need to remove the line `textBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black` to stop if from been `black` on every click. Set it to `black` in your form's constructor.

Comment: Yours is the most helpful answer so far, but as the others have pointed out, initially setting the colour to black will only ever cause the first condition to be triggered.

Comment: This does not help in the current state since the first line still makes the rest pointless.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I though I hadn't copied that line - doh - I'll remove it now, and clarify my answer.

Comment: @user1803685: The first time you click.  Click again.

Comment: @user1803685 See my last paragraph (just edited it) and Tim's comment about it been always black.

Answer (score 8):

You always set the color to black to begin with.

The logic ends up being:

```
Set the color to black.

Is it black? Yes - change to red.
Is it red? Yes - change to green.
Is it green? Yes - change to blue.
Is it blue? Yes - change to red.
```

Don't do that.

Move the initial setup to the class constructor and return from the function as soon as you set a color (or use `if/elseif/else` constructs).

Comment: Yes, because else the code wont run. It tells when it is black then color = red

Comment: @user1803685 - But you do this on _every_ button click. You should initialize it in the constructor. The way you are doing it, the colors will never cycle.

Comment: Ok, how can i fix this? It needs a break or something.

Comment: @user1803685: Set the initial textbox color to black, using the Properties pane in Visual Studio.  You don't need the first line setting it to black, not even in the constructor.  As Dave Shaw points out, you need `else` `if`'s.

Answer (score 4):

You are setting your BackColor to Black on the first line, so you will always hit your first case and it will change to red.

A switch statement might make your code a little nicer looking if you are so inclined...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        switch (textBox1.BackColor.ToKnownColor())
        {
            case KnownColor.Red:
                textBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;
            case KnownColor.Green:
                textBox1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                break;
            default:
                textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Tested.  Works now. I was using a non-constant in switch, sorry.  However there is a nice "KnownColor" Enum for such a situtaion, if you are using a "KnownColor" (Red, Green, and Blue are pretty well known).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Queue<Color>` to determine which `Color` is next, and always switch it when you click the button.

```
private Queue<Color> colors = new Queue<Color>();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Here you set the order that the colors will be set in.
    colors.Enqueue(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
    colors.Enqueue(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    colors.Enqueue(System.Drawing.Color.Gray);
    colors.Enqueue(System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox1.BackColor = colors.Peek();

    //move the color at the front to the back of the queue
    colors.Enqueue(colors.Dequeue());
}
```

Comment: @user1803685 "Didn't work" is pretty meaningless.  What happened?  Did you get an error, was it a runtime or compile time error?  What was the error?  Did something undesirable happen, if so, what?  Did you make any changes, if so, what?

Answer (score 0):

This is to be facetious.  I tested this code and it works, not recomeneded for ANYONE at any time, this is just to be goofy because we didn't have a LINQ answer yet, and I will remove it if requested but, here is an example of using an inline if inside of a LINQ statement to find the color you are looking for.  Did I mention this works?

```
        textBox1.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(((KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)))
            .Where(c => c + (textBox1.BackColor == Color.Red ?
                (int)KnownColor.DarkSlateBlue : textBox1.BackColor == Color.Green ?
                (int)KnownColor.Chartreuse : (int)textBox1.BackColor.ToKnownColor() - (int)KnownColor.Red)
                == textBox1.BackColor.ToKnownColor())
                .FirstOrDefault());
```